# Android Run program only on 800*480 devices

Tags: android

How can i do that? The only way to declare its to the manifest?

Comment: @Matt—I assume it’s referring to the screen resolution. 480×800 is a pretty common one among Android devices.

Comment: I assumed that, too, until reading the end of the sentence: _"CPU greater than 800mhz"_

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to ask "how can I force this application to only be installed on 800x480 devices", the answer is, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width and height of the screen using the following piece of code and use if/else statement to run the code only if the screen is bigger than 800*480

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Hope it helps :) Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to support mdpi screens with 480*800 resolution you can try adding this to your manifest file:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: whats happening when a smallScreens user run this app? nothing?